# Is it possible to use Image Set in a Xamarin Forms

Tags: image, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to add some Images as Image Sets in a Xamarin.Forms project. I followed this [guide](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_images/displaying-an-image/#asset-catalogs) . But the icon is not displayed. Is it possible actually to use Image Sets in a Xamarin Forms Solution for the iOS project?

```
<Image VerticalOptions="Center"
                    HorizontalOptions="End"
                    Source="check_outline_500_active.png"
                    WidthRequest="40">
                    </Image>
```

Comment: Emulator or device, which iphone?

Comment: For debugging I am using an Emulator (iPhone 6s iOS 9.2)

Comment: Try to add images in resources folder under xamarin ios project and rename file like : check_outline_500_active.png, check_outline_500_active@2x.png, check_outline_500_active@3x.png

but in code use : check_outline_500_active.png

Comment: @PuchoEric this is working for me. The problem is when I follow the new  guidelines to add them as Image Sets.

Comment: okay, i'll put it as answer

Comment: @PuchoEric Image sets are the newer "version" of the selectors `@2x, @3x, ~iphone, ~ipad`

Comment: @Sven-MichaelStübe ah oki oki

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes you can.

- create the Asset catalog
- add Image Set and name it "check_outline_500_active" (**without .png**)
- add the images
- done

[image]

**my xaml**

```
<Image VerticalOptions="Center"
    HorizontalOptions="Center"
    Source="check_outline_500_active.png">
</Image>
```

**Result**

[image]

**Note**

You might have to delete mtbs (on the mac) and bin/obj (on your project) or the build cache can fool you :)

Comment: On Xamarin Studio how can I create the Assets Catalog? Is it a simple folder?!

Comment: So basically the problem was that instead of creating a new Asset Catalog file, I just created a new folder naming it Images.xcassets.

Answer (score -1):

Try to add images in resources folder under xamarin ios project and rename file like :

check_outline_500_active.png,

check_outline_500_active@2x.png,

check_outline_500_active@3x.png

but in code use : check_outline_500_active.png