# Xamarin.Forms iOS images not showing

Tags: image, xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have a Xamarin.Forms shared project. On Android all images work fine. I wanted to add them to my iOS project, but they don't show. I've added them to Assets.xcassets:

```
{
  "filename": "logo_launcher.png",
  "scale": "1x",
  "idiom": "universal"
}
```

And I use the following XAML:

```
<Image Source="logo_launcher.png" x:Name="logo" />
```

I've added all images except for the vector ones. I'm testing it on a iPhone 8 - 11.4 simulator.

Although it is deprecated, I tried to add the images to the "Resource" folder. But I couldn't even select the .png files. So that didn't work either.

I'm lost at what to do. Is there some option I need to enable, or something to include in the XAML to make it work?

Comment: Cannot comment but check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36798182/8057282

Comment: I've followed that, unfortunately that doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

Just select all images in resources folder in **ios** and `right click-->build action-->bundle resource`. It will work.

Answer (score 1):

Check/Reproduce some steps below:

1. Check the build action on your image resource, in shared PCL it should be `Embedded Resource`, in Android the build action should be `AndroidResource`and `BundleResource` in iOS
2. Try to set `Copy to output directory` to `Always copy`
3. Delete bin/obj folders, switch build configuration from debug to release, rebuild project and then back to debug
4. Try to delete the image from iOS, rebuild, re-add again, and then repeat the steps above

Also, you can try to set the `ImageSource` as you can see below:

```
<Image x:Name="logo"> 
    <Image.Source> 
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="ImageSource"> 
            <On Platform="Android" Value="logo_launcher.png"/>
            <On Platform="iOS" Value="logo_launcher"/>
        </OnPlatform> 
    </Image.Source> 
</Image>
```

I hope this can help you.

Comment: There is a change I'm just stupid, but I'm not able to do step 1 and 2 on the assets.xcassets catalog. The other steps where not successful.

Comment: You don't need to use assets.Xcassets

Comment: Yes I do: "Prior to iOS 9, images were typically placed in the Resources folder with Build Action: BundleResource. However, this method of working with images in an iOS app has been deprecated by Apple. For more information, see Image Sizes and Filenames." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=vswin

Comment: I didn't know, I will have a look. Tks bro

Comment: @TruffelNL please, check the possible solution that I found.

Comment: @TruffelNL, if the solution still not working for you, send me the project if it is possible (PoC/Prototype), I can try to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I found a [possible solution](https://github.com/jboliveira/XForms.Sample.ImageRes) using Assets.xcassets, check the steps below:

1. Main.xaml

   ```
   <Image x:Name="iconBrain">
       <Image.Source>
           <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="ImageSource">
               <OnPlatform.iOS><FileImageSource File="IconBrain"/></OnPlatform.iOS>
               <OnPlatform.Android><FileImageSource File="ic_brain"/></OnPlatform.Android>
           </OnPlatform>
       </Image.Source>
   </Image>
   ```
2. Android: Add the images on the respective Drawable folders under Resourses directory.
3. iOS: Create a new Image Set under Assets.xcassets and add the Images.
4. Done. No extra properties, configs, or xamarin tricks.

Check out [my GitHub](https://github.com/jboliveira/XForms.Sample.ImageRes) for the full solution, also I tried to reproduce the same environment w/ Xamarin.Forms, Shared Project and iPhone 8 - 11.4 simulator.

Another point, you can't add the images under mipmap directories, because the mipmap folders are for placing your app/launcher icons (which are shown on the homescreen) in only. Any other drawable assets you use should be placed in the relevant drawable folders as before.

> It’s best practice to place your app icons in mipmap- folders (not the drawable- folders) because they are used at resolutions different from the device’s current density. **- [Google blogpost](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2014/10/getting-your-apps-ready-for-nexus-6-and.html)**

Finally, thank you for the information about the deprecated approach by Apple.

> Prior to iOS 9, images were typically placed in the Resources folder with Build Action: BundleResource. However, this method of working with images in an iOS app has been deprecated by Apple. For more information, see [Image Sizes and Filenames](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/images-icons/displaying-an-image?tabs=vsmac). **- [Images in Xamarin.Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=vswin)**

I hope this can help you.