# Xamarin forms - Menu icon on ios

Tags: ios, xaml, xamarin, xcasset

I have this `MasterDetailPage`.

On UWP and Android the upper left icon of the menu is showed correctly, but on iOS appears the label "Menu".

I have an image "Hamburger" inside the `xcassets`, and I would like to use it.

How can I make this works?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Menu_TEST.Views"
            x:Class="Menu_TEST.Views.MainPage">

    <MasterDetailPage.Master>
        <views:MenuPage />
    </MasterDetailPage.Master>

    <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
        <NavigationPage>
            <NavigationPage.Icon>
                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource">
                    <On Platform="iOS" Value="Hamburger"/>
                </OnPlatform>
            </NavigationPage.Icon>
            <x:Arguments>
                <views:ItemsPage />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
    </MasterDetailPage.Detail>
</MasterDetailPage>
```

Comment: Use `Title="☰"` inside `MasterDetailPage.Master`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have an image "Hamburger" inside the xcassets, and I would like to use it.

If want to get image from `xcassets` ,you can refer to [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36796571/is-it-possible-to-use-image-set-in-a-xamarin-forms).However this maybe can not work here in `MasterDetailPage.Master`.So suggest that better use the image from Resources folder.

```
<MasterDetailPage.Master>
   <views:MenuPage />
</MasterDetailPage.Master>
```

From your code , `MenuPage` is setted to the `MasterDetailPage.Master` property. If want to set icon to the upper left,you need to set in `MenuPage.xaml` as follow.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="AppMasterDetail.Views.MenuPage"
             Title="Menu"
             Icon="hamburger.png"> //Here set icon ,image from 'Resources' folder

    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <ListView x:Name="ListViewMenu"
                    HasUnevenRows="True">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid Padding="10">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="20"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

If not have this `hamburger.png` in project, you also can set title like CGPA6.4 said that.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                 x:Class="AppMasterDetail.Views.MenuPage"
                 Title="☰">  //Here change 'Menu' to '☰'
        ...

 </ContentPage>
```

Here is [a official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/master-detail-page) with [sample](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/Navigation/MasterDetailPage/) , you can refer to.